# Angularjs - Get today's date and display next 6 days from that

Tags: angularjs

Please check the following snippet. I need an output like I did in the sample using AngularJS ng-repeat. I tried a lot but not working. So here I just created a sample code output, I know you might expect more code, but so far what I tried is full or errors. Please help.

```js
function dateCtrl($scope){

$scope.todayDate = new Date();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<p ng-app ng-controller="dateCtrl">

<a><span>Today</span></a>|
<a><span>Tomorrow</span></a>|
<a><span>Wed 3 Apr</span></a>|
<a><span>Thu 4 Apr</span></a>|
<a><span>Fri 5 Apr</span></a>|
<a><span>Sat 6 Apr</span></a>|
<a><span>Sun 7 Apr</span></a>|
</p>
```

Comment: you want to show current date and next as today and tomorrow also?

Comment: yes, first two days as mentioned in the output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this will help you. Thank you.

```js
function dateCtrl($scope){


        $scope.todayDate = [];
        var tempDate = [];
        tempDate.push(new Date());
        for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
          tempDate.push(new Date());
          tempDate[i].setDate(tempDate[i].getDate() + i);
        }
        $scope.todayDate = tempDate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<p ng-app ng-controller="dateCtrl">

        <a  ng-repeat="dates in todayDate">
            <span ng-if="$index==0">Today | </span>
            <span ng-if="$index==1">Tomorrow | </span>
            <span ng-if="$index>1">{{dates | date : "EEE, d MMM" }} | </span>
        </a>

</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exact answer. You saved my weekend.

Comment: Please check integrate it into your code and confirm it is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I check it with my code and it is working. Thank you.

Comment: This is a wrong answer, as getDate() return an integer based on the day of month. If you are on the 30th of a month and you add 6, you simply get 36 (which is not a valid day of any month)